# drools decision table exists keyword

Tags: drools

currently my drools decision table looks like next:

```
|CONDITION|CONDITION|
---------------------
|      Person       |
---------------------
|name=$1  |age=$1   |
---------------------
|         |         |
---------------------
|a        |22       |
---------------------
|b        |33       |
---------------------
```

now i want to make this decision table looks like next in .drl file :

```
rule "1"
when
    exist Person(name=="a",age="22")
then
    do something
end

rule "2"
when 
    Person(name="b", age="33")
then
    do something
end
```

so how to modify the decision table to achieve my goal?

that is how to use 'exists' keyword in decision table file?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
| CONDITION  | CONDITION |
--------------------------
|     exists Person()    |
-------------------------
|name==$param|age==$param|
---------------------
|            |           |
---------------------------
|a           |22         |
---------------------------
|b           |33         |
--------------------------
```

The other rule is almost the same; just omit the exists. However, one such table can only produce rules according to one template. Therefore, you'll get either two rules (a/22, b/33) with exists, or the same pair without.

To have rules according to both templates, you need two different `RuleTable`s.

Comment: if like what you said in decision table file, actually both these 2 rules has 'exists Person()' in .drl file, what i want is : 1st rule has 'exists Person()', while 2nd rule only 'Person()'.

Comment: If `Person()` matches, then `exists Person()` is also true. So it achieves nothing to try to avoid the `exists` match in the second rule.

Comment: @Steve The "achieves nothing" isn't quite right. It may be quite useful to have one action depending on the existence of >= facts of a kind while still being required to do something else for each of them.

Comment: @laune, do you mean one RuleTable only can has one rule? but i have many rules, so if one RuleTable only has one rule, then it will has many RuleTable.  Also, this results in duplicate condition and action header.

Comment: @frank One Rule Table can create many rules **according to the structure defined by the Rule Table's header**. According to your example: if there is an `exists` in the second row, all rules have this `exists`; if it is omitted, no rule derived from that Rule Table has it. If you have many rules and they all have different **structure**, a decision table doesn't make much sense.